# Catch/Suppress OpenCV warnings sent to std::cout

Tags: c++, opencv

When a camera is attached AND you supply `VideoCapture` with an unmapped `int DeviceID`, OpenCV outputs (to `std::cout`, mind you) `Unable to stop the stream: Invalid argument`.

How can I catch/suppress this?

Comment: I think you can derivate what you need from the example here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/
This example explain how to redirect `std::cout` stream to a file and reset to the noraml `stdout` file after.

Comment: IIRC [`cv::redirectError`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga8cd28eccccb695570cdaf86a572d2c0c) is what you're looking for -- at least for any messages coming from OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`cv::redirectError`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga8cd28eccccb695570cdaf86a572d2c0c) function to handle any messages (such as asserts) yourself. For example, to simply silence the output, you could use the following piece of code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int dummy_error_handler(int status
    , char const* func_name
    , char const* err_msg
    , char const* file_name
    , int line
    , void* userdata)
{
    //Do nothing -- will suppress console output
    return 0;   //Return value is not used
}

void set_dummy_error_handler()
{
    cv::redirectError(dummy_error_handler);
}

void reset_error_handler()
{
    cv::redirectError(nullptr);
}
```

Note: If the actual message comes from another source, such as a third party library that OpenCV uses, a different approach will be necessary.

Comment: Try as I might, it doesn’t appear that rederiecting error catches it. I’m still trying to investigate what calls it with minuscule luck thus far.

Comment: @xOtik I found those messages in [cap_v4l](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4eb296655958e9241f43a7bd144d5e63759f6cea/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L1868) and cap_libv4l, where for some odd reason the author chose to use `perror`. (Don't see it used anywhere else) As such, the above won't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Would rebuilding OpenCV modifying these lines to suppress the output/change it so it’s catchable, or just cause mass chaos? The c++ 11 docs on `perror` doesn’t explicitly state it returns after being called.

Comment: @xOtik `perror` should just print the error message and return, so pretty much anything ought to be fine. You could comment those lines out, or you could edit them to use something like `CV_Assert` or use `cv::error` directly, taking advantage of `strerror` to format the current system error like `perror` does. It's the messages generated through `cv::error` that `redirectError` can handle.